# It there a "Spring way" to get an implementation from an annotated interface?

Tags: java, spring, interface, annotations, spring-aop

I want to scrap some boilerplate. Say I have a custom interface with custom annotations:

```
interface MyInterface {
    @DoSomething("crazy")
    public String aMethod(int numberOfJumps); 
}
```

Now I can write an `InvocationHandler`, and generate a `Proxy` implementation which does something more or less useful based on the annotation and method arguments, and returns an appropriate result. This works fine.

My question is if I could use some mechanism from Spring to get the same result, but maybe safer, faster, more flexible and/or more configurable. The Spring AOP annotations look promising, but they seem to require a class, not an interface.

**[Update]**

In order to make clear what I want here the outline of my current code:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    @MyAnnotation(name = "foo")
    public void testMethod(String arg);
}

public class AnnotationProxy {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getImplementation(Class<T> annotatedInterface) {
       return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(annotatedInterface.getClassLoader(),
               new Class<?>[]{annotatedInterface},
               new AnnotationHandler());
    }

    private static class AnnotationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Args " + Arrays.toString(args));
            System.out.println("Annotations" + Arrays.toString(method.getAnnotations()));
            return "useful value";
        }
    }
}

TestInterface ti = getImplementation(TestInterface.class);
String s = ti.testMethod("xyz"); //"useful value"
```

As you can see, I create an object out of thin air (and some ugly reflection stuff). I want to know if I can to do this in a more civilized and spring-like way.

Comment: Not sure but You can have xml approach of spring aop for interface methods.

Comment: I'm not sure that using annotated interfaces is a good practice, for example when using CGLIB proxies I believe the information about interface method annotations will be gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to scan for interfaces which have methods with your favorite annotation, create and register proxies in the Spring application context.

**Example**

Let's have an interface `Test` which we want to create and register the proxy for:

```
package com.test;

public interface Test {
    @DoSomething(pattern = "[%s]")
    void print(String value);
}
```

Our annotation looks like this:

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DoSomething {

    String pattern();

}
```

And we would like to use it in an application like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.test.Test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");
        final Test test = ctx.getBean(Test.class);
        test.print("Hello");
    }
}
```

Our *test.xml* Spring configuration file contains just a scan for components:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
</beans>
```

Not to the point. In order to create and register proxies we have to implement [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) to scan for the interfaces and create proxies:

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata;
import org.springframework.core.type.MethodMetadata;
import org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MetadataReader;
import org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DoSomethingPostprocessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private Object createDoSomethingBean(final MethodMetadata mmd, final Map<String, Object> attributes)
            throws Exception {
        final String pattern = (String) attributes.get("pattern");
        final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(mmd.getDeclaringClassName());
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { clazz },
                new InvocationHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public Object invoke(final Object proxy, final Method method, final Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                        System.out.println(String.format(pattern, args[0]));

                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        try {
            final String packageSearchPath = "classpath*:com/**/*.class";

            final Resource[] resources =
                    applicationContext.getResources(packageSearchPath);
            final SimpleMetadataReaderFactory factory = new
                    SimpleMetadataReaderFactory(applicationContext);

            for (final Resource resource : resources) {
                final MetadataReader mdReader = factory.getMetadataReader(resource);

                final AnnotationMetadata am = mdReader.getAnnotationMetadata();
                final Set<MethodMetadata> methodMetadata =
                        am.getAnnotatedMethods(DoSomething.class.getName());
                for (final MethodMetadata mmd : methodMetadata) {
                    final Map<String, Object> attributes =
                            mmd.getAnnotationAttributes(DoSomething.class.getName());
                    final String beanName = mmd.getDeclaringClassName();
                    beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, createDoSomethingBean(mmd, attributes));
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks very promising!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring AOP to intercept and post process annotated methods:

```
@Aspect
public class ProcessDoSomethingAspect {

    @AfterReturning(value = "execution(@annotation(doSomething) * *.*(..))", returning = "result")
    public String processResult(my.package.DoSomething doSomething, String result) {
        // process result here
        return result;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have an *interface*, not a class, so how do I get an implementation from this?

Comment: do you want to get access to intercepted object in aspect?

Comment: No, I want to *create* a new object without writing a class, based only on the interface and AOP magic or so

Comment: And how do you expect to define behavior for this new class?

Comment: The behaviour should be defined *only* by AOP: It should read annotations and method args, calculate a value and return it. Without any "real" method.

Comment: I don't think AOP is about constructing classes, it is about intercepting calls for existing classes.